# How to deploy SpringBoot on external Webserver?

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a SpringBoot Application. It is using embeded-Tomcat by default. I want to deploy this on my Production Server which is Tomcat8 located on Linux Machine.

How to achieve this?

Comment: If your application has an embedded Tomcat container, then the fact your production service is running Tomcat 8 is irrelevant, apart from the fact that you'll have to make sure your ports don't conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reading the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) might help :)

This [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/) should also be helpful.